# Makefile fails on specifying OBJDIR containing directory path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want the targets (*.o and .a) to be on specific directory rather than the being on the same directory where make is currently running. I find below code from GUN to create target on specific directory; It works well, if I specify OBJDIR := objdir; but makefile fails if I specify OBJDIR := /home/user/mytarget

```
 OBJDIR := objdir
 OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

 $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c     
            $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

 all: $(OBJS)

 $(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

 $(OBJDIR):
            mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

I tried specifying strip like OBJDIR := $(strip $(TARGET)) where my target is /home/user/mytarget. Please let me know, how can I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works if `OBJDIR := objdir`, and you're going to have trouble with that `$(OBJDIR):` rule, but I think this change will solve your problem:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I still find the issue. I aligned the Makefile so that it would be easy for you now to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer: 
I find there was a space on declaring TOP_DIR (marked with _ for space)

TOP_DIR := /home/usr/_
so when I echo'ed of OBJDIR,

DIR := mytarget
OBJDIR := $(strip $(TOP_DIR)$(DIR))

OBJDIR = /home/usr/_mytarget

which was wrong; on removing space from TOP_DIR, it worked.

Comment: When editing makefiles it's best to use an editor which has a "makefile editing" mode.  Those modes will allow you to visualize whitespace issues that happen with makefiles.